How to correctly multiply homomorphically two RLWE-Based encrypted numbers
Assume that I have two ciphertexts,$c_1=(u_{0},v_{0})$ and $c_2=(u_{1},v_{1})$, encrypted by RLWE scheme and  I wanted to do only one homomorphic multiplication, i.e., $c_1*c_2$. What is the correct way to do so without evaluation key and bootstrapping.
Is it simply $c_1 * c_2=( u_{0}*u_{1},v_{0}*v_{1})$.
Or it's like $c_1 * c_2=( u_{0}*u_{1},u_{0}*v_{1}+ v_{0}*u_{1},v_{0}*v_{1})$.
If it's the latter, how to relinearize it?.
Note: I mentioned no evaluation key and bootstrapping because I only need to do exactly one multiplication and I choose an error vector with very small coefficients.

It's the later. To relinearize it, you need a relinearization key (something morally akin to $\mathsf{Enc}_s(s\ast s)$).
You're saying you don't have this, so you can't relinearize it.
You can still decrypt it though, which is probably what you care about.
How I like to think about this (and the way that it makes it very clear, at least in my opinion) is that a ciphertext $c_i := (u_i, v_i)$ isn't just a pair of polynomials, it's a pair of polynomials such that
$$
v_i - u_i\ast s =\Delta m_i + e_i.
$$
So, if we want an encryption of $m_0\ast m_1$, we can write
$$
(\Delta m_0 + e_0)\ast (\Delta m_1 + e_1) = (v_0-u_0\ast s)\ast (v_1 - u_1\ast s).
$$
Expanding the left-hand side, we get
$$
\Delta^2m_0\ast m_1 + \Delta (m_0\ast e_1 + e_0\ast m_1) + e_0\ast e_1.
$$
Expanding the right-hand side, we get that
$$
v_0\ast v_1 - (u_1\ast v_0+u_0\ast v_1)\ast s + u_0\ast u_1 \ast s \ast s.
$$
Dividing this by $\Delta^2$, we get that
$$\tag{0}\label{eq:0}
m_0 \ast m_0 + \frac{m_0\ast e_1+e_0\ast m_1}{\Delta} + \frac{e_0\ast e_1}{\Delta^2} = \frac{v_0\ast v_1}{\Delta^2} - \frac{(u_0\ast v_1+u_1\ast v_0)}{\Delta^2}\ast s + \frac{u_0\ast u_1}{\Delta^2}\ast s \ast s.
$$
So, provided
$$
\lVert\frac{m_0\ast e_1+e_0\ast m_1}{\Delta} + \frac{e_0\ast e_1}{\Delta^2}\rVert_\infty < 1/2,
$$
if we compute the RHS of Eq. \eqref{eq:0}, and then round each coefficient to the nearest integer, we will get back $m_0\ast m_1$.
So, one can multiply $(u_i, v_i)$ without a relinearization key by computing the (non-standard) ciphertext
$$
(c_0, c_1, c_2):=(v_0\ast v_1, -(u_0\ast v_1+u_1\ast v_0), u_0\ast u_1).
$$
One then decrypts this ciphertext via
$$
\lfloor\frac{c_0+c_1\ast s + c_2\ast s \ast s}{\Delta^2}\rceil
$$

Thanks much Mark. Sorry but why did you use the delta (triangle) symbol? what is its value in this context?. Could you thankfully clarify it more.

Lattice crypto has to include a scaling factor to the message (or error, but I chose message above) to be able to correctly decrypt later, even without homomorphic operations. I wrote this as $\Delta$. Some people write it as $q/p$ to encrypt numbers mod $p$.

Which homomorphic scheme, published paper, is the closest to the method you provided?

Decrypting an unrelinearized ciphertext? I've used it (for LWE, with the LWE tensor product, rather than RLWE polynomial products) in Section 5 of this CRYPTO paper. That is mildly more complex though, because the analogues of the terms $(v_0\ast v_1, -u_0\ast v_1-u_1\ast v_0, u_0\ast u_1)$ are very large for LWE, so we used a trick to "squash" them to be smaller using RLWE.

That being said, the fact that unrelinearized ciphertexts themselves are still decryptable is pretty basic. I'm sure a comment to this extent occurs in some of the earlier ~2012 works on FHE, but don't have time to hunt for a citation now myself.

@MarkSchultz-Wu There's a minor typo, $u_0 * u_0 *s * s$ should be $u_0 * u_1 * s * s$. Is division by $\Delta^2$ taking place in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ or in $\mathbb{Q}$? Similarly, is $\Delta$ an integer, or an integer modulo $q$?

@JacksonWalters division occurs within $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\Delta\in\mathbb{Z}$. Practically one has to be careful that arithmetic occurs with enough precision so that the above products are computed exactly over $\mathbb{Z}$ before dividing by $\Delta^k$ (and perhaps truncating the high-precision integers). As a very simple example, in 1D if you have $u_0, u_1, s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that each has absolute value $\leq 2^{16}/2$, then $\left\lfloor\frac{u_0u_1s^2}{\Delta^2}\right\rceil$ (with $\Delta := 2^{16}$, for example) will require higher than 16-bit arithmetic to compute correctly.
